# string to boost posix_time then back again

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

Not a problem here, just a curiosity really. I'm wondering about amount of code I've had to write to achieve this when a similar operation with other language's dateTime implementations would have only been 3 or 4 lines.

So what I've got is a timestamp as a string ie: `06-Feb-2013 00:01:01`

and through using the boost lib, I would create the input and output facet, create a stringstream and imbue the io facets into the stream. Then I would read the timestamp string into the stringstream before shifting it out to a posix time object to added 1 second to it before shifting it back into the stream so I can use it as a string. In a sense all I'm doing here is turning a timestamp like `06-Feb-2013 00:01:01` into `06-Feb-2013 00:01:02`.

An example of would be:

```
using namespace boost::posix_time;

ptime timeStamp;
time_facet* outFacet = new time_facet("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S");
time_input_facet* inFacet = new time_input_facet("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S");
std::stringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale::classic(), outFacet));
ss.imbue(std::locale(ss.getloc(), inFacet));

ss.str(06-Feb-2013 00:01:01);
ss >> timeStamp;
timeStamp+=seconds(1);
ss.str("");
ss << timeStamp;
```

The code works, I have no problems with it. I'm just wondering if I've done this in a roundabout way considering in python/ruby/js etc, all I would have had to do was something along the lines of:

```
dt = new DateTime("06-Feb-2013 00:01:01", aformat);
dt.addSecond() //or dt += another DateTime object
dt.strformat(aformat) //or trace/print/puts dt
```

Now I appreciate that C++ is lower level but I still can't help wondering. So any improvements or thoughts?

Comment: seems about rite, if you were to follow through any of the other languages implementations, it would probably be just as verbose. Not having to do it yourself is what the price of admission is paying for when you choose to go with a scripting language instead of playing close to the metal

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to accept a slightly different (fixed) time format, using std::string to_simple_string(ptime) (to format YYYY-mmm-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff string where mmm 3 char month name. Fractional seconds only included if non-zero, per http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) could simplify your code to do output formatting along with corresponding "ptime time_from_string(std::string)".